# unsuccesfully trying to add integers of an array in function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, oop, object

I'm writing a program to add up a student's 5 scores.

I have successfully read 5 integers in an object function called `input()`, which assigns the values to the private `int[]` array named `scores`.

However, I cannot return the sum from the `calculateTotalScore()` function.

The output that is given by the Eclipse compiler when I try to run it, using 5 integers I chose for `scores`, is the following:

```
40 60 80 90 22
```

So it's outputting the numbers I'm giving it, but it's not doing any addition of integers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    int scores[5];
    int sum;
public:
    void input();
    int calculateTotalScore();
};

void Student::input() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        int grade;
        cout << "Enter your score" << endl;
        cin >> grade;
        scores[i] = grade;
    }
    //checking that the array are being stored.
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int);i++){
        cout <<scores[i] << " " << flush;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// returns the sum of the students scores
int Student::calculateTotalScore(){

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int);i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return sum;
    //Check that the numbers are adding up correctly
    cout << sum;
}

int main() {

    Student Kristen;
    Kristen.input();
    Kristen.calculateTotalScore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're returning from `calculateTotalScore` before you print the sum.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Pop quiz: what is the initial value of `sum`, before you try to add everything to it? Is it 0? Is it 42? Is it the answer to life, the universe, and everything?

Comment: and `sum` should not be a member of `Student`, but a local variable of `calculateTotalScore`.

Comment: This is one of those things that would be pretty easy to spot stepping through the code in your debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok I have initialized 'sum' to 0 and now it gives me the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are seeing is from the `cout` statements in `input()`, that is why you see all of the numbers you typed in.

`calculateTotalScore()` does not output anything to `cout`, because it `return`s before it reaches that point in the code.  The `cout` statement is unreachable.  Your compiler should be warning you about that.

`calculateTotalScore()` should not be trying to output to `cout` at all. That is better done by `main()` instead, where `calculateTotalScore()` returns a value to it:

```
int Student::calculateTotalScore(){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int);i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    ...
    cout << Kristen.calculateTotalScore();
    ...
}
```

---

On a side note, all of your `sizeof()` usages should be replaced with a single `const` variable instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    static const int NumberOfScores = 5;
    int scores[NumberOfScores];

public:
    void input();
    int calculateTotalScore();
};

void Student::input() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfScores; i++) {
        int grade;
        cout << "Enter your score" << endl;
        cin >> grade;
        scores[i] = grade;
    }

    //checking that the array are being stored.
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfScores; i++){
        cout << scores[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// returns the sum of the students scores
int Student::calculateTotalScore(){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfScores; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    Student Kristen;
    Kristen.input();
    cout << Kristen.calculateTotalScore();
    return 0;
}
```

In the real world, students are likely to have a variable number of scores, so consider using `std::vector<int>` instead of a fixed `int[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int Student::calculateTotalScore(){

for (int i=0; i < sizeof(scores) / sizeof(int);i++){
    sum += scores[i];
}
return sum;  <- Code returns to previous call

//Check that the numbers are adding up correctly
cout << sum; <- Code never reaches this point as it always returns
```

Your function returns when you tell it to return.

cout << sum; is what is called **unreachable code**

Good idea to know what it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code